# A commercial jet with rear tail-mounted engines and 3+3 seat pattern?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane, seats, seating-capacity

I have just spotted a cameo in one of the old CSI:NY episodes. External shot showed a commercial jet, rather big aircraft, with rear tail-mounted engines. While internal shots shown 3+3 seat rows configuration and around 150-180 passengers.

Is this *combination* ever possible or is this an in-movie mistake?

I was always told that rear tail-mounted engines are capable of powering smaller aircraft only (like MD-8x and Canadairs) which are always configured in 2+2 seat rows set and are capable of delivering around 100 passengers at most.

What am I missing (note that I am *not talking* about trijets)?

Comment: The interior shot was probably of a different aircraft. DC-9 and MD-80 aircraft are 5 abreast with up to 150 passengers.

Comment: The Vickers VC10 was not a "smaller" aircraft.

Comment: The Internet Movie Plane Database lists only 2 commercial aircraft for CSI:NY.  [A 727 and a 767.](https://www.impdb.org/index.php?title=CSI:_NY)

Comment: Only thing I could find with tail-mounted engines and 3+3 seating is the [Tu-334](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-334), but only 2 were ever built and ironically it is smaller (seats about 100).

Comment: @fooot: The 727 (one of which, as Gerry says, is explicitly mentioned by IMPDB as having shown up in CSI-NY) had three engines, all tail-mounted, _and_ six-abreast seating, _and_ the ability to carry (for the 727-200) up to 189 passengers.

Comment: @Sean but the last line of the question says "note that I am *not* talking about trijets". Other than that I agree the 727 makes the most sense here.

Comment: @fooot: The 727's middle engine is buried in the tailcone and easily overlooked; it's likely that what he thinks was a twinjet was actually a 727 that he didn't notice the middle engine of.

Comment: @trejder Your mistake is assuming that the editors of a TV show would care about that sort of technical consistency on something like a secondary scene with filler like that.  The interior shot and exterior shot will have absolutely no connection - the exterior shot being a stock clip grabbed from somewhere by someone with no clue or care.

Comment: John K nailed it.  TV and movies are well known for mixing things up like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it was a season 5 episode, [it was most likely N7264U, a 727-200](https://www.impdb.org/index.php?title=CSI:_NY#Season_Five):<sup>1</sup>

> ## Season Five
>
> #### Boeing 727-222
>
> Ep. 5.25
>
> Registration N7264U, c/n 21411/1346 built in 1978 for United. Based at Ontario International Airport (ONT/KONT) in California, where this was most likely filmed.

The 727's three [Pratt & Whitney JT8D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_JT8D) engines [are all mounted on/in its tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727#Design), and the plane was large enough to have six-abreast (3+3) seating, as can be seen in this 727-200 seatmap found via a quick google (this particular seatmap is for an EAL 727, but the 3+3 seating was common to all passenger 727s of which I am aware):

[image: 727 seatmap]

(Image by Eastern Airlines, via Darren at [Frequently Flying](https://frequentlyflying.boardingarea.com/vintage-airline-seat-map-eastern-airlines-boeing-727-200-177-seats/).)

And the 727-200's maximum passenger capacity was [189, according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727#Specifications), although it more usually carried 134 (in a two-class configuration) to 155 (all-economy arrangement), so it fits the 150-180-passenger requirement (and even exceeds it slightly at the upper end).

And yes, I know it's a trijet, but:

- the #2 engine is buried within the 727's tailcone and mostly concealed from view, unlike the large, obvious pods holding the #1 and #3 engines (as opposed to, say, a DC-10, whose centerline engine and associated intake duct form a huge conspicuous cylinder above the fuselage at the base of the vertical stabiliser);
- as for the centerline engine's tailpipe (which *is* visible, sticking out the tip of the tail, if you look carefully), the JT8D is a slim low-bypass turbofan, making for a much narrower and less obtrusive tailpipe compared to the chunky high-bypass engines that occupy the tailcone of (say) an L-1011 or Yak-42;

...and, putting both of those together, and considering that it was a (presumably brief) cameo giving no reason, and little opportunity, for you to pay close attention to the tip of the aircraft's tailcone, it's perfectly possible that what you saw *was*, in fact, a (trijet) 727, and that you simply didn't notice the easy-to-miss-at-a-brief-glance middle engine.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Thanx to Gerry [for providing the link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70608/a-commercial-jet-with-rear-tail-mounted-engines-and-33-seat-pattern#comment183955_70608).